# Removing the last characters in an XSLT url string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a URL in XML I am trying to pass through an xsl v.1. The xml contains random numbers after the url starting with '?'.

```
<Pictures>
  <url>http://photos.somewhere.cm/82873604/photos/1.jpg?20161010170035</url>
  <url>http://photos.somehwere.cm/82873604/photos/2.jpg?20161010170035</url>
<Pictures>
```

Currently my xsl looks like

```
<attachments>
  <xsl:for-each select="Pictures/url">
    <image>
      <xsl:value-of select="url" />
    </image>
  </xsl:for-each>
</attachments>
```

How do I get rid of all the text after '?' and only remain with the url

```
<attachments>
  <image>http://photos.somewhere.cm/82873604/photos/1.jpg?</image>
  <image>http://photos.somehwere.cm/82873604/photos/2.jpg?</image>
<attachments>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Saidia.

Comment: Well, XSLT 1.0 builds on XPath 1.0 so check the XPath 1.0 spec for a function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before doing the job.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
<attachments>
  <xsl:for-each select="Pictures/url">
    <image><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(node(),'?')"/></image>
  </xsl:for-each>
</attachments>
```

Thanks for the tip @[M. Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen)